# How to read a column to a table that was deleted by mistake.

Tags: sql, nopcommerce

I deleted the IsGftCard when using WebMatrix - Definition Editor. I put the IsGiftCard back with editor, gave it a bit - data type, and tried to change the Data Value to false, as it does not work with Null characters but web matrix gives an error when I try and save the file

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsGiftCard', table 'incrediblebranding.dbo.ProductVariant'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

So I allow Null characters to allow the file to be saved, but when I try and go to the site (localhost) on my PC I get the following error in Internet Explorer.

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsGiftCard', table 'incrediblebranding.dbo.ProductVariant'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.SqlDatabase.SqlDatabaseProvider.EditTable(String connectionString, String schema, TableInfo tableInfo)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.IisDbManagerModuleService.EditTable(DatabaseConnection databaseConnection, String schema, Object tableInfoData, String configPathState)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientConnection.EditTable(String schema, Object tableInfoData)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientTable.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.TableDesignerViewModel.PerformSave(). error
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The 'IsGiftCard' property on 'ProductVariant' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.ConstraintException: The 'IsGiftCard' property on 'ProductVariant' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'.

```
Source Error: 


Line 76:         <div class="clear">
Line 77:         </div>
Line 78:         @Html.Action("RecentlyViewedProductsBlock", "Catalog")        
Line 79:         <div class="clear">
Line 80:         </div>        


Source File: c:\Users\USER\Documents\My Web Sites\nopCommerce\Views\Shared\_ColumnsThree.cshtml    Line: 78 

Stack Trace: 


[ConstraintException: The 'IsGiftCard' property on 'ProductVariant' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'. ]
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +105
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +1240
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +218
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +215
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +170
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +84
```

There is a lot more to this error but I cut it short. Is there anyway to edit the product_variant file to change the default value to False and to save the .dbo. file. Or is there a way of replacing the product_variant file altogether. I am very very new to this, if you could help, Mark